# Object[key] is not constructor

Tags: typescript

I have a command, which implements a interface.

My Command.

```
import iCommand from './i-command';


export default class Voice implements iCommand {
  args: String[];    
  message: any;
  client: any;
  config: any;

  constructor(args: String[], message: any) {
    this.args = [];
    this.message = {};
    this.client = {};
    this.config = {};
  }

  test() {
    console.log('run');
  }

  setClient(client: any) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  setConfig(config: any) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  runCommand(): void {
    const emoji = this.message.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'alpha_flag');
    this.message.channel.send('test').then(newMsg => {console.log(emoji); newMsg.react(emoji)});
    this.message.channel.send('test').then(newMsg => {console.log(emoji); newMsg.react(emoji)});
    this.client.channels.get(this.config.infoChannelId).send(`:fire: **Voice voting for player ${this.args[0]} started at** #voicing :fire:`);
    this.client.channels.get(this.config.voiceChannelId).send(`:fire: **Voting for player ${this.args[0]}** :fire:`).then(
      message => message.react(emoji)
    );
  }
}
```

My interface:

```
export default interface iCommand {
  args: Array<String>;
  message: any;
  client: any;
  config: any;
  runCommand(): void;
  test(): void;
  setClient(client: any): void;
  setConfig(config: any): void;
}
```

Dictionary:

```
import Voice from './voice';

export const Commands = {
  'voice': Voice
}
```

and CommandManager:

```
import {Commands} from './commands/commands';
import iCommand from './commands/i-command';

export default class CommandManager {
  client: any;
  config: any;

  constructor(config: any) {
    this.config = config;
    this.client = {};
  }

  setClient(client: any) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getCommand(key: any, args: String[], message: any): void {
    let command: iCommand = new Commands[key](args, message);
    command.test();
     // @ts-ignore
    command.setConfig(this.config);
     // @ts-ignore
    command.setClient(this.client);
     // @ts-ignore
    return command;
  }
}
```

How does it work? When user use command for example `.voice`, `commandManager` using key return command. But... Whatever i do. `Commands[key]()` is not constructor. You know what is funny. Method test is working, but error `typeError` disable my promises. I was tried to disable ts-error, but it didn't work too... Where I have error? Should I use `typeof` in key?

Answer (score 1):

In the class CommandManager the method getCommand has a wrong signature. The key has any type

```
 getCommand(key: any, args: String[], message: any): void {
```

which is wrong since key can only be 'voice'. One way to fix this would be to change the type of key to 'voice' (see below). The method's return type should also be iCommand and not void. Void means that the method doesn't return any value.

```
getCommand(key: 'voice', args: String[], message: any): iCommand {
```

you can support multiple values for key. You can define a new type that contains all the possible keys:

```
type CommandType = 'voice' | 'text';
```

and getCommand would look like this

```
getCommand(key: CommandType, args: String[], message: any): iCommand {
```

Comment: So I was changed everything like u said. But Can you explain more about a CommandType?

Comment: The command type is either the string 'voice' or the string 'text'. You could of course expand that to cover all of your use cases. However, I would use enums if I were you